# how to print all text in a specific tag using xpath in python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am new to python and xpath. And I am trying to print the text inside the tag 'p' from an html file.
I have this portion of code:

```
<section>
    <p>Hello <br>nnn</br> <a href="google.com"> dfgdfg </a> World!</p>
</section>
```

I want to print: `Hello nnn World!` and The code I am using is:

```
for el in html.xpath('//section/p'):
    print (el.text)
```

But the printed text is only: Hello
Can any one help me solve this?

Comment: what are you using? `lxml`? `soup`?

Comment: @eLRuLL using lxml

Answer (score 2):

use `text()` inside the xpath directly:

```
for el in html.xpath('//section/p//text()'):
    print (el)
```

Check the `//` says to get all text from all nodes inside the current `p`.

to print all together, try:

```
print(''.join(html.xpath('//section/p//text()')))
```

Comment: its not working. If I print(el) it prints all the text in the 'p' tag but each portion in a new line

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: @fiscsp: If this answer had helped, please accept it out of courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `XPath` `'//section/p/text()'` as below to get `Hello nnn World!`:

```
for el in html.xpath('//section/p/text()'):
    print (el, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `text_content`.

```
   for section_p in html.xpath('//section/p'):
       print section_p.text_content()
```